# Delphi XE8: TEdit TextHint Disappears When Receiving Focus

Tags: delphi, focus, delphi-xe8, editcontrol

Basically, I want the TextHint of my TEdits to disappear when the first character is entered and not when they receive focus, like the Edits on this Microsoft page: [Sign in to your Microsoft account](https://login.live.com/). Can someone please walk me through on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Uwe Raabe's answer, here is a procedure (for Delphi 2007, should work for newer versions of Delphi as well):

```
type
  TCueBannerHideEnum = (cbhHideOnFocus, cbhHideOnText);

procedure TEdit_SetCueBanner(_ed: TEdit; const _s: WideString; _WhenToHide: TCueBannerHideEnum = cbhHideOnFocus);
const
  EM_SETCUEBANNER = $1501;
var
  wParam: Integer;
begin
  case _WhenToHide of
    cbhHideOnText: wParam := 1;
  else //    cbhHideOnFocus: ;
    wParam := 0;
  end;
  SendMessage(_ed.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, wParam, Integer(PWideChar(_s)));
end;
```

You call it like this:

```
constructor TForm1.Create(_Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TEdit_SetCueBanner(ed_HideOnFocus, 'hide on focus', cbhHideOnFocus);
  TEdit_SetCueBanner(ed_HideOnText, 'hide on text', cbhHideOnText);
end;
```

It doesn't check for the Windows version though, you might want to add the if statement Uwe provided:

```
if CheckWin32Version(5, 1) and StyleServices.Enabled and _ed.HandleAllocated then
```

I just tested it with a project where I disabled runtime theming: It didn't work.

Comment: Regarding your edit to my answer: SendMessage doesn't compile as Value is a string. That is why SendTextMessage is used (at least in D2009+).

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I looked up SendTextMessage and couldn't find anything apart from sending SMS. Where is SendTextMessage declared? Is it an RTL function or Windows API?

Comment: It is declared in (Winapi.)Messages since D2009 and wraps the ugly casting. Quite handy when LPARAM must point to a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Uwe and dummzeuch for submitting your answers! I really appreciate it. After some research on creating components I was finally able to create my own (sorry, I don’t know how to highlight text) THintEdit and THintLabeledEdit, which worked perfectly!

Comment: Will this work with `TComboBox` as well dummzeach and @UweRaabe?

Comment: @LuiP3rd I haven't tested it, but it might. Did you try it?

Answer (score 8):

The built-in `TEdit` behavior doesn't allow this, but you can derive a new control from `TEdit` and override `DoSetTextHint`. The implementation should be similar to the internal method, but provide a value of 1 for `wParam` instead of 0.

This is a solution using an [interceptor class](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/interceptor.htm):

```
unit EditInterceptor;

uses
  Vcl.StdCtrls, System.SysUtils, Winapi.Messages, Windows;

type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  protected
    procedure DoSetTextHint(const Value: string); override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Themes, Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TEdit.DoSetTextHint(const Value: string);
begin
  if CheckWin32Version(5, 1) and StyleServices.Enabled and HandleAllocated then
    SendTextMessage(Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, WPARAM(1), Value);
end;

end.
```

Make sure to place this unit in the interface uses clause after *Vcl.StdCtrls*.